# What is Ideal ways to use AWS SNS to send OTP during Registration?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am trying to understand how efficiently I can use AWS SNS service to send OTP for the first time registration person.

What I have understood till now is in SNS I have to register the Mobile no and then only AWS can send text to that subscriber.

However my case I wanted to create registration page where user will enter its cell phone contact number and I will have to send text OTP on the same.

In current architecture of AWS SNS first I will have to register each and every cell phone number in my AWS account, and then only it is possible to send messages.

Is this the right approach ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PinPoint send messages api instead of SNS.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/send-messages-sms.html

Comment: it is still problem since, I need to register all cell phone numbers with AWS service, since my case it is registration process, is it great idea ?

Comment: The reason is because you are using sandbox, you will need to move the Pinpoint account to production https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/channels-sms-awssupport-sandbox.html